# Effective Refractive Index in Paper

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, refraction

I am reading the paper, entitled "Artificial uniaxial and biaxial dielectrics with use
of two-dimensional subwavelength binary gratings" by Eric B. Grann, M. G. Moharam, and Drew A. Pommet. https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-11-10-2695

In the paper they mention this formula:

> [image]

**Do you know how it can be derived and where it comes from ?**