# Effective Refractive Index: Where does this formula come from?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, refraction

In the paper, entitled "Artificial uniaxial and biaxial dielectrics with use
of two-dimensional subwavelength binary gratings" by Eric B. Grann, M. G. Moharam, and Drew A. Pommet. https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-11-10-2695,  they mention this formula:

> [image]

**Does anyone know where this formula comes (references if possible) from (and maybe how it can be derived) ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542409/2451

Comment: Hi james. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh, I thought that I had deleted the other question.. oh well, sorry for that